# How I can call specified first app's rake task from second one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rake-task

How can I call specified 1st app's rake task from second one.

Case:
User on baseapp.com (RoR), fills up the reg.form
BaseApp validates and stores data
Than, with delayed_job/resque I should call subapp's rake db:bootstrap FORM_PARAM1 FORM_PARAM2 ... FORM_PARAM3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need define the Rakefile you want load to your rake execution

```
rake -f my_dir_1/Rakefile my_task
rake -f my_dir_2/Rakefile my_task_2
```